# Multiple computers with same ssh Private and Public keys

Tags: ssh, private-key, public-key, openssh

I have about 12 computers with exactly same specs. These are used for my PoS on my business.

I am creating a customized Ubuntu ISO to improve installation time and automate things.

One issue I am facing is OpenSSH-server generated keys (Pub and private), must be generated after installation through command `ssh-keygen` ...

However, I have to pass explicit and plain-text password, which I would like to avoid.

I would like to know if I can share same private and public keys to everyone, so that I can remote connect on them?
In this way, I can generate keys only once and seed it through post-script installation using pressed.

Answer (score 0):

> One issue I am facing is OpenSSH-server generated keys (Pub and private), must be generated after installation through command ssh-keygen...

They are generated after the installation for a reason. And that reason is certainly that they should not go to anyone else (from there is the **private** word). But they are **Host** keys.

> However, I have to pass explicit and plain-text password, which I would like to avoid.

Why? You can store your public key on them and you would be still able to connect with your private key, which will be still safe.

> I would like to know if I can share same private and public keys to everyone, so that I can remote connect on them? In this way, I can generate keys only once and seed it through post-script installation using preseed.

You can, but it is certainly not advised and fail-prone technique possibly leading to the compromised security.

Comment: I am creating an automated installation iso, which in order to be automated, I must inform the password in plain-text due to initial ssh-keygen configuration

Comment: It didn't explain anything.